# Do python multiprocessing pools share memory or they convey their own exact copies into another memory space?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

When I use Pooling in python does each process create its own copy of the given data exactly or it extracts the interest region? Is there any way to limit those processes to copy only the interest region for each ?

Answer (score 0):

You're overestimating multiprocessing.  It uses `os.fork()` to make new processes (which is fast) but then it uses `pickle` to pass all data back and forth.  On Windows, not having `fork()`, it is a worst hack: new processes are started and initialized by running the same code as the parent program, hoping that nothing too bad occurs.

Comment: So you mean all the given data to be processed by the pool is copied as whole for each process right ? Or do they use same address space and memory location?

Comment: If you use `Pool().map(f, [args..])`, then `args` is copied around using `pickle`.  As far as I know `Queue` and `Pipe` are the same.  The only exception is the section [Sharing state between processes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) in the docs.